# Unordered list in AEM/CQ - Parsys

Tags: aem, sightly

How can I utilise the WCM Parsys component to create an unordered list of multiple instances of another specific component in AEM 6?

I need to ensure that the list is wrapped by a `ul` tag, that each inner component is an `li` tag, that no extra `div` tags are wrapped around the `ul` or `li`s and ensure the properties of each inner component can be edited in author mode.

(My attempts so far either have loads of extra `div` tags, ruining the already built layout and semantics, or if using `decorationTagName='li'` the editor-boxes for the components all sit on top of each other in author mode so you can only edit the topmost control).

Answer (score 3):

Check out Sightly when you are working with AEM 6. It provides a nice way to add parameters to child resources, when iterating over them ... this allows you to add resources types. This is a nice way for aggregating components. Feike Visser wrote a nice five page long [tutorial](http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/sightly-intro-part-1/).

Listing children via Sightly is not obviously easy.

```
<ul>
  <!--/* for example jcr:content */-->
  <div data-sly-list.par="${resource.listChildren}"
       data-sly-unwrap>
    <!--/* for example a parsys */-->
    <div data-sly-list.item="${par.listChildren}"
         data-sly-unwrap>
      <!--/* all children of the parsys rendered with an li tag */-->
        <div data-sly-resource="${item.path @ wcmmode='disabled'}"
             data-sly-unwrap></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

This will render the children of a content reosource's parsys. A elegantly way would be using a model provided via JavaScript, WCMUse or a SlingModel. But this way you can skip the programming for easy iterations. Checks for resource names work as well, so you can add a bit more of complexity, although you will want to use an appropriate model in complex scenarios.

Comment: thanks, I'm already using Sightly, but can't figure out how to use a Parsys to output a <ul><li>component</li><li>component</li></ul> type structure

Comment: The tutorial URL you gave is no longer valid. I think this is the new URL: http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/sightly-intro-part-1/

Answer (score 2):

The OOTB parsys component uses divs to wrap around the inner components, so if you need a completely different structure you need to go for a custom parsys that extends from the existing one and uses a different wrapping markup.

Comment: Any idea where one can learn about extending the parsys component?  I can't seem to find any tutorials just by searching Google.

Answer (score 1):

What I do usually is to create an own container component where I have a switch between author mode and publish/preview mode. E.g. in Author mode just display the child components in a normal parsys with divs and only render the correct markup in the preview/publish mode:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${isEditMode}">
        <cq:include path="par" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <ul>
            <c:forEach items="${m.components}" var="comp">
                <li><cq:include path="${comp.path}" resourceType="${comp.resourceType}" /></li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Whereas `m` is a controller and `components` is a list of child `Resource`'s.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the components inside the parsys are list-item components (and only used that way), you can override the element wrapping your component with the `cq:htmlTag/cq:tagName` property, and making your parsys render the `<ul>` elements.

For more information, see [ComponentDiv](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/ComponentDiv.html)